# python bot adding and not using minus

Tags: python

```
from random import*
N = int(input("n="))
while N > 20 and N < 50:
    while True:
        bot = (randint(1, 6))
        br =(N-bot)
        print(br)
        x = int(input("nombre de bille retire ="))
        br=(N-x)
        while br == 0:
            print("tu as gagne")
        br = (N-x)
        if br==0:
            print("tu as perdue")
```

when I use this code the bot just adds numbers instead of dividing.

Comment: How do you plan to leave the 2nd loop?

Comment: Do rephrase your question again. First, there is no addition operator, so the question title doesn't make any sense, and in the description, there is no division operator too in your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that you can just run. Remove everything not necessary, like e.g. manual input. Preferably, also references to volatile things like the filesystem, the date/time and random numbers. Also, include expected and actual output in your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: its a game that runs on luck so the first one to reach  0 loses but instead of dividing N by bot it just adds it

Comment: i am sorry i meant substraction not deviding

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation and the code, I guess the game goes as follow :

1. The user choose a number between 20 and 50
2. The bot subtracts a random number between 1 and 6, if the result fall to 0 or below it loose
3. The user choose a number to subtract, if the result fall to 0 or below he loose
4. repeat from 2

If that's correct there are many issues with your code. This should work:

```
from random import*

#Initial choice
while True:
    br = int(input("Choisissez un nombre entre 20 et 50 : "))
    if br > 20 and br < 50 :
        break

while True:
    #Bot turn
    bot = (randint(1, 6))
    br = br - bot
    print(f"Billes retirées = {bot}, billes restantes = {br}")
    
    if br <= 0:
        print("tu as gagné")
        break
        
    #User turn
    x = int(input("Nombre de billes à retirer ="))
    br = (br - x)
    print(f"Billes restantes = {br}")
                  
    if br <= 0:
        print("tu as perdu")
        break
```